# Freeform 4 - send from email field

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way in Solspace Freeform 4 to have the admin notifications sent "from" or "reply-to" the value an email field? That way when the admin receives a notice that a form had been submitted with a question, they can simply hit reply? I have a number of clients that forget to copy/paste the email in the body of the notification.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I had given up searching documentation with no answer, I find an answer. While I didn't find it documented, in the notification templates, you can use something like "{email}" in the reply-to field.

Comment: Could you use the answer field to answer yourself and mark it as accepted (as soon as it will allow!). Just helps keep questions and answers stats up to date. Thanks.

Comment: Add {email} to the from field in your notification template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like "{email}" in the reply-to field